# Can I have multiple else if statements if they are not nested?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklett and can get this to work by removing all the other else if statements but one ie if / else if / else thats it... But not with all of them... wondering if they should be nested?

```js
if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("leads/process") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: leads");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("apply-continue/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Apply Continue");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("apply/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Apply");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("answered-call/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Answered Call");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("contact/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Contact");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("contact-us/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Contact Us");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("maintenance-request/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Maintenance Request");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("online-application/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Online Application");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("rent-now/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Rent Now");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("request-info/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Request Info.");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("suggestion-box/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Suggestion Box");
}  else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("tour/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Tour");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("tour-request/submissions") > -1 {
   alert("GOAL ID: Tour Request");
} else {
   alert("CUSTOM GOAL ID: Goal ID used is not in the standard set.");
}
```

Comment: This is completely fine. Put end brackets `)`.

Comment: make it more readable by putting `document.documentElement.outerHTML` into a variable.

Comment: @epascarello Do you mean like this?

var source = documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to nest your if statements, what you have is nearly ok, except you are missing the end brackets on your if conditions, try:

```
if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("leads/process") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: leads");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("apply-continue/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Apply Continue");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("apply/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Apply");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("answered-call/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Answered Call");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("contact/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Contact");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("contact-us/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Contact Us");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("maintenance-request/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Maintenance Request");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("online-application/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Online Application");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("rent-now/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Rent Now");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("request-info/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Request Info.");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("suggestion-box/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Suggestion Box");
}  else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("tour/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Tour");
} else if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("tour-request/submissions") > -1 ){
   alert("GOAL ID: Tour Request");
} else {
   alert("CUSTOM GOAL ID: Goal ID used is not in the standard set.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks dtkaias but after converting this to a script there are still unexpected results. Not running.

Comment: What are the unexpected results? Are the any error messages?

Comment: I am not getting any alerts when i use the bookmarklet. There is an else catch all so if anything it should tell me my else alert right?

Comment: Looks like i misplaced one of the brackets in the code in my answer, I've updated it now. A quick way to test if the code works is to paste the code into your browser's Javascript console, this way it will print out errors if there are any, as a bookmarklet it seems to just do nothing if there is a syntax error.